# how to make website circular progress bar which which changes starting point?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

[Check This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fDo8.jpg)I want to Make a Circular Progress Bar for my Website.Which Change Its Starting Point With Button Click. For Example, When Button 1 Clicked It Should Rotate From 270 Degrees, When Button 2 Clicked It Should Rotate From 0 degree,When Button 3 clicked It Should Rotate From 90 degrees and When Button 4 Clicked It Should Start from 180 degrees.....
Please Help Me
Thanks In Advance..

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with that? Can you explain us further? Can you post an image of your website just to see how does your button behave?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow - please consult this help article http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Comment: Attached Image,,What I exactly Want is When I Click On Animation button The Progress Bar Start From Left Most Corner Of The Button And Then Make A Circle...and same for rest of the buttons ..Hope U Got @GeorgeGkas

Comment: @Prokor I think I get it.

Comment: Add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Keep in mind first that this is not a clear answer, cause a right one would take me time of coding.*

I recently used a open-source library from github. Here is the link.
https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

It is exactly what you want (with some modifications).

Here is the example. https://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/

If you see the fourth progress circle, you see that you can set your own starting angle.

Let me here explain how can this achieve having  Example four as my reference:

```
/*
 * Example 4:
 *   - solid color fill
 *   - custom start angle
 *   - custom line cap
 *   - dynamic value set
 */
var c4 = $('.forth.circle');

c4.circleProgress({
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 4 * 3,
    value: 0.5,
    lineCap: 'round',
    fill: { color: '#ffa500' }
});
```

With  `StartAgle` you  can set the start value of the progress bar.
You can easy update your code to make the circle over and over again until the content you want load.
See the usage of the library here : https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress#usage

See that answer too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371976/4108694

Comment: thanks a lot.... @GeorgeGkas

Comment: @Prokor if you have any question please comment me. Also you can always up vote and approve my answer.